# Prisma 2: Connecting record to implicit many to many table

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I am using Prisma 2 and am having trouble connecting existing records on a model that has an implicit many to many relationship with the connected model.

### schema.prisma

```js
model Event {
    id              Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    performers      Performer[]
}

model Performer {
    id              Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
    events          Event[]
}
```

After running prisma migrations, I can see in postgres that I do have a join table created named `_EventToPerformer`. I have created some performers in my database, and when I try to create an event and connect those existing performers, I am not able to.

```js
const performers = await prisma.performer.findMany()

const event = await prisma.event.create({
      data: {
        performers: performers.map((p) => ({ id: p.id })),
      },
      include: {
        performers: true,
      },
  });
```

For the above code, I am getting fairly cryptic typescript errors on the `data` property of the object I am passing in to the create function. When I suppress with `@ts-ignore`, I getting these prisma client errors:

```
Unknown arg `performers` in data.performers for type EventUncheckedCreateInput. Available args:

type EventUncheckedCreateInput {
      id?: Int
    }
```

Is there anything obvious I am missing when setting up an implicit many to many relationship, and/or attaching existing records to these models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `connect`. So you're code should look like:

```
const performers = await prisma.performer.findMany()

const event = await prisma.event.create({
      data: {
        performers: {
          connect: performers.map((p) => ({ id: p.id })),
        }
      },
      include: {
        performers: true,
      },
});
```

You can read more about working with relations [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes)